# Unit Test: How to mock document.getElementById() in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, dom, jestjs

I want to test following code with jest.

Does anynoe know how to mock **document.getElementById()**?

```
if (document.getElementById('estateList')) {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <EstateList />
        </Provider>,
        window.document.getElementById('estateList')
    );
}


if (document.getElementById('articleList')) {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ArticleList />
        </Provider>,
        window.document.getElementById('articleList')
    );
}

if (document.getElementById('articleDetail')) {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ArticleDetail />
        </Provider>,
        window.document.getElementById('articleDetail')
    );
}
```

I think I can put render inside a function, like:

```
function estateList() {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <EstateList />
        </Provider>,
        window.document.getElementById('estateList')

    );
}
```

Then simply test estateList(), without mocking **document.getElementById()**, but is there anyway to mock **document.getElementById()**?

Comment: Instead of using `document.getElementById()`, you can try (if possible) using a `ref`. IE, `<EstateList ref={(element) => {this.element = element;}} />`, and then you can replace occurences of `document.getElementById()` with `this.element` instead, and your tests should run fine too.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme . It makes it very easy to create wrappers and explore them.

Answer (score 3):

Using [jest.fn(implementation)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestfnimplementation) create mocked `getElementById` method and replace the method on `document`.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

export const store = createStore(() => 0);

export const EstateList = () => <div>EstateList</div>;
export const ArticleList = () => <div>ArticleList</div>;
export const ArticleDetail = () => <div>ArticleDetail</div>;

function bootstrap() {
  if (document.getElementById('estateList')) {
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <EstateList />
      </Provider>,
      window.document.getElementById('estateList'),
    );
  }

  if (document.getElementById('articleList')) {
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ArticleList />
      </Provider>,
      window.document.getElementById('articleList'),
    );
  }

  if (document.getElementById('articleDetail')) {
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ArticleDetail />
      </Provider>,
      window.document.getElementById('articleDetail'),
    );
  }
}

export { bootstrap };
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { bootstrap, store, EstateList, ArticleList, ArticleDetail } from './';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

jest.mock('react-dom');
const mockedRender = render as jest.Mocked<typeof render>;

describe('49146453', () => {
  let oGetElementById;
  beforeAll(() => {
    oGetElementById = document.getElementById;
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    document.getElementById = oGetElementById;
  });
  it('should render estatelist', () => {
    document.getElementById = jest.fn().mockImplementation((id) => (id === 'estateList' ? 'estateList-dom' : null));
    bootstrap();
    expect(mockedRender).toBeCalledWith(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <EstateList />
      </Provider>,
      'estateList-dom',
    );
  });

  it('should render articleList', () => {
    document.getElementById = jest.fn().mockImplementation((id) => (id === 'articleList' ? 'articleList-dom' : null));
    bootstrap();
    expect(mockedRender).toBeCalledWith(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ArticleList />
      </Provider>,
      'articleList-dom',
    );
  });

  it('should render articleDetail', () => {
    document.getElementById = jest.fn().mockImplementation((id) => (id === 'articleDetail' ? 'articleDetail-dom' : null));
    bootstrap();
    expect(mockedRender).toBeCalledWith(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ArticleDetail />
      </Provider>,
      'articleDetail-dom',
    );
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/49146453/index.test.tsx
  49146453
    ✓ should render estatelist (6ms)
    ✓ should render articleList (1ms)
    ✓ should render articleDetail (1ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |    84.21 |      100 |       40 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |    84.21 |      100 |       40 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.618s, estimated 11s
```

The version about `jest.js` and related packages, check source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/49146453